# What does "snap" mean?

Tags: meaning

> Use your voice to snap apps, switch instantly, and start
>   recording game clips.

I referred to a dictionary (https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/snap), and it seems that none of its definition fits in. Or Does it mean "move quickly" (one of the meanings for "snap"), which means "to open apps quickly"?

Comment: Please tell us the source of the quotation. Where exactly did you read this? Can you link to the source.  (You don't need to comment, please just [edit] your question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that *snap* is being used a verb. (Not as a noun, which could apply to Ubuntu's type of [*Snap* applications](https://itsfoss.com/snap-store/).)

As a verb, it's likely something that Windows does (if not other operating systems, although I'm not sure).

From ["How to Snap Apps Side by Side in Windows 10"](https://www.dummies.com/computers/operating-systems/windows-10/how-to-snap-apps-side-by-side-in-windows-10/) by Ciprian Adrian Rusen:

> If you need to work with two apps at the same time in Windows 10, it’s a good idea to snap them side by side so that each consumes half of the screen. To snap one app to the left, use the mouse to drag the title bar of the first app to the left side of the screen.

Apparently, the sentence in the question is describing how to accomplish this with voice commands.

---

Of course, this could likely be confirmed if the source of the sentence were provided.